# Multiple fullscreen sections with absolute positioned divs inside

Tags: html, css, height

I'm creating a website and I want each section to take up the full screen.  I have:

```
 html, body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
```

and each section has 100% height and width and relative position.  Inside the second section, I want to create four divs that take up each corner. They share a class which has height and width 50% and absolute position. I tried to position them individually by selecting each id and giving them top:0 left:0, top:0 right: 0, and so on.

The problem is, the left and right positioning works, but when I try to position the top or bottom, the div will go to the top or bottom of the first section instead of the second.  I think it might be an issue with having two 100% divs on top of each other, but I'm not sure.  Would really appreciate any advice!

Comment: I also tried to create two divs within the second section, each with a height of 50%, and then placing two divs on the left and right side of each of those. That hasn't worked either.

Comment: not sure what problem you have (or i understand it right) but i create a sample like you mention and it work fine like this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/vr3zacr4/)

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: @HenryVarro I tried implementing what you did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3hz3u7z0/), and I still get the same problem where the squares overlay my first div. If you comment over the .same2 part of the css, you can see that theres another div being covered.

Answer (score 1):

After see your fiddle, i see you wrote wrong the word "**position**" in class "**.work**", beside you can add an div clear between two divs "**.hero**" and ".**work**", it will work

```
<!--==== HEADER =============================================-->

        <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
                 --><li><a href="#">Work</a></li><!--
                 --><li><a href="#">About</a></li><!--
                 --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- container -->
        </div><!-- header -->


        <!--===== HERO =============================================-->

        <div class='hero' data-type="background" data-speed="10">
            <div class='name'>
                <h1>kdjfkd</h1>
                <h2>fdasfdr</h2>
                <h2><span >fgafd</span></h2>
            </div>
        </div><!-- hero -->
<div style="clear:both"></div>


<!--   ============= WORK ==================     -->

        <div class='work'>

            <div class="same2" style="background-color:red; top:0;left:0"></div>
            <div class="same2" style="background-color:yellow; top:0;right:0"></div>
            <div class="same2" style="background-color:white; bottom:0;left:0"></div>
            <div class="same2"style="background-color:green; bottom:0;right:0"></div>

        </div>
```

```
 .work{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3hz3u7z0/1/)
Edit: not need "**clear:both**" at all, it still work fine